# Dumping data to existing yaml file with yaml code inside

Tags: python, dataframe, yaml, pyyaml

I'm dumping some data from an .csv file to .yml file using yaml.dump.
My problem is that when i dump data to the .yml file. All the current yaml iside of it vanishes and only the new yaml from the .csv file shows.

Examples:

Before I dump yaml to .yml file:

```
Text: 'This is some yaml'
MoreText: 'This is more yaml'
```

After I dump yaml (All the current yaml vanihes and only the new shows):

```
NewYamlFromCsvFile: 'This is new yaml'
```

What I want:

```
Text: 'This is some yaml'
MoreText: 'This is more yaml'
NewYamlFromCsvFile: 'This is new yaml'
```

Here's my yaml.dump code:

```
            yaml.dump(
            df.loc[(df['NAME'] == pack)].to_dict(orient='records'), # Send keywords to the right pack, etc java keywords to java pack.
            outfile,
            sort_keys=False,
            width=72, 
            indent=4
        )
```

I there any way to not delete the current yaml when new yaml is dumped? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the output file in 'a' mode (append mode):

```
with open('output.yml', 'a') as outfile:
       yaml.dump(your_data, outfile, other_args )
```

Comment: Yessss! Thank you